# Proof that entropy of Markov Source is $H(S) = \sum_s P(s) H(s)$

Tags: markov-process, information-theory, entropy

Let $S$ be a markov source in which distribution $P$ doesn't depend on $P_0$ and which generates numbers from finite set $\Omega$. Proof that
$$H(S) = \sum_{s \in \text{process states}} P(s)H(s) $$
where
$$H(s) = \sum_{x\in\Omega} P(x| s) \log P(x | s)$$

### My attempt

According to the definition of the entropy, for discrete random variable $X$ with possible occurrences $x_1, ..., x_n$ it is $H(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(x_i)\log P(x_i)$. So in my case, $X$ would be $S$ and $x_i, ... x_n$ would be $s_1, ..., s_n$. Then:
$$H(X) =H(S)= -\sum_{i=1}^n P(s_i) \log P(s_i) $$

So I want that $ - \log P(s_i) = H(s_i)$
But I don't know how to proceed with that further. I also looked for that in some books but I didn't find any proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A random process $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ is associated with an *entropy rate*, defined as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{H} &=& \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}H(X_n, X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)  
\end{eqnarray*}
(when the limit exists). If the process is stationary, as it appears to be in your example, then you can use an equivalent definitions for entropy rate:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{H} &=& \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} H(X_n | X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

The definition that makes sense to use in the case of a stationary Markov process is the second one. In your example, it appears that you are assuming a Markov source of order 1 (the current symbol depends on only one past symbol). In that case
\begin{eqnarray*}
H(X_n | X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)  = H(X_n | X_{n-1}) = H(X_1|X_0) 
\end{eqnarray*}
where the last equality follows from the stationarity of the process. Then the equation for the entropy rate that you mentioned follows trivially, as
\begin{eqnarray*}
H(X_1|X_0) &=& \sum_{x_0} p(x_0) \sum_{x_1} p(x_1|x_0) \log \frac{1}{p(x_1|x_0)} \\
&=&\sum_{x_0} p(x_0) H(X_1 | X_0 = x_0)
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, you have one more additional condition in your problem which is that "$P$" does not depend on "$P_0$".  It isn't immediately clear what exactly you mean, but with high likelihood, you are trying to state that the stationary distribution of the Markov chain does not depend on the distribution of the initial state. This condition is not strictly needed to obtain the entropy formula above, however that condition is often very useful when one wants to study how the probability of long sequences is associated with the entropy.

If the stationary distribution does not depend on the initial conditions, the Markov chain is "ergodic". One of the consequences of ergodicity is that empirical averages converge to the expectation with probability 1, as the number of samples being averaged goes to infinity; specifically if $E[X_0] < \infty$, for a stationary and ergodic random process,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_i f(X_i) = E[X_0]
\end{eqnarray*}

with probability 1. If you plug in $f = \log P_{X_1|X_0}$, then you obtain that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_i -\log P_{X_1|X_0}(X_i | X_{i-1}) = E[-\log P(X_1|X_{0})] = H(X_1|X_0)
\end{eqnarray*}
with probability 1. So ergodicity makes entropy meaningful - it can be used to estimate the probability of long sequences of symbols, regardless of how the sequence starts.

For further references, take a look at the classical book Elements of Information Theory by Cover and Thomas.

Comment: I don't understand 1 thing. What is $X_1$ and $X_0$ in that task? I mean that for one variable it seems that I have to use symbols $x \in \Omega$ and for the second $s \in $ States.

Comment: The answer describes a "plain" Markov process in which the observables $X_0, X_1, X_2, \cdots$ are the Markov chain states themselves. Your question did not describe a specific model for the observables (other than saying they are numbers coming from a finite set $\Omega$) so this is the simplest assumption that fits all your assertions.

Comment: In a previous comment (which now appears deleted) you had asked how did the fact that $P$ does not depend on $P_0$ get used. While this assumption itself needs a bit more clarification, the answer above was updated to more sharply talk about ergodicity.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate your support and I am going to write up your ideas connected with points from mentioned book and my solution in a document. I can share that when I finish.

Comment: I have one more question. By this $H(X_n | X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)  = H(X_n | X_{n-1}) = H(X_1|X_0) $ you mean Markov source of order 1, but what in general case? When Markov source has order $k$. Then this formula is also correct and following your solution we get $H(X_k | X_{k-1}, ..., X_{0}) = -\sum_{x_0,..., x_k}p(x_{k}, ... x_0) \cdot p(x_k|x_{k-1}, ..., x_0)$ - how to get thesis from that point? I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: You have a typo in your formula, add $\log$ before $p(x_k | x_{k-1},\cdots,x_0)$. A similar derivation, as you noted, can be used for Markov chains of arbitrary order (as long as they are stationary).